# How to use query to get today's date activities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

```
  TodayCheckedStatus = (from checkinout in context.Checkinout
                        join status in context.Status on checkinout.CheckType equals status.Statusid
                        where checkinout.Userid == userinfo.Userid
                        where checkinout.CheckTime == DateTime.Today.Date       
                        orderby checkinout.CheckTime descending
                        select new Checkinout
                        {
                         CheckStatus = status.StatusText,
                         CheckTime = checkinout.CheckTime
                         }).ToList()
```

I used this but for a reason it doesn't work it shows nothing in the page

```
          where checkinout.CheckTime == DateTime.Today.Date
```

Comment: What type is `checkinout.CheckTime`? Is it a DateTime type? If it is a DateTime type, does it have some value in the time portion of the DateTime?

Comment: Yes it is DateTime type and yes it has time value but i only need the date to be today's date

Comment: This is LINQ to EF (probably), not SQL. Which version are you using? In SQL you would write `WHERE cast(CheckTime as date) = @date` where `@date` is a parameter with type `date`, not `datetime`. Different EF versions have different ways of invoking SQL functions though

Comment: BTW you shouldn't be using joins like this when working through an ORM. It's the *ORM*'s job to generate joins from the relations between entities. Nor do you need *multiple* `where` statements. The result is equivalent to `AND`

Comment: @E.Lahu you're problem is that `DateTime.Today.Date` gives you todays date with the time part as [midnight, everithing as 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.7.2). You're trying to compare that to a DateTime that actually has time. So it's never going to be the same.

Comment: @E.Lahu you should do something like this `where checkinout.CheckTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date `

Comment: @ikerbera Thanks man this is working now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to reiterate the response from @ikerbera in an answer, the required change was

```
where checkinout.CheckTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date
```